# header and footer that always appear at top and complete bottom

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, css, visual-studio-2008

I know I can just use a master page, but what markup do I use on the master page to always have a header at the top and a footer all the way at the bottom using some CSS code?

Comment: We'd love to, but could you rephrase your question so that we can understand it? Your first sentence doesn't seem to make any sense (to me, at least).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the footer:

It's called a Sticky Footer.  You can google it and find some (google `css sticky footer`).  I like this [one](http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/).

Comment: That is actually better than my answer, as it scrolls and doesn't take up the space all the time. Repeating the height in the padding is a bit ugly, but otherwise, it looks clean.

Comment: please see this link and help if possible http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4059485/the-footer-css-does-not-work-when-the-page-loads-dynamic-content-at-button-click

Answer (score 3):

Although I am not perfectly sure, what your context is, in general you can do this by setting `display:fixed` for your footer and header id/class and using `bottom:0` for the footer and `top:0` for the header.

You probably want to include a high `z-index` for both so they are always displayed at the upper-most layer.

The problem with this solution is that the actual content of the page scrolls behind both items, and may be unreadable, so you have to tweak the top and bottom `margin` for both.

This is a quick and dirty information to get you started, as you did not provide more details in your question.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4059485/the-footer-css-does-not-work-when-the-page-loads-dynamic-content-at-button-click

Answer (score 1):

Use `position: fixed`

So a header might be:

```
.header {
     position: fixed;
     top: 0px;
     left: 0px;
     width: 100%;
     height: 100px;
}
```

And a footer:

```
.footer {
     position: fixed;
     bottom: 0px;
     left: 0px;
     width: 100%;
     height: 50px;
}
```

That would be a 100px high header and a 50px high footer at the bottom. Note that `position: fixed` does not work in IE6 by default

Comment: i used your method, but problem is with dynamic content please refer ths link, see if a solution exists. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4059485/the-footer-css-does-not-work-when-the-page-loads-dynamic-content-at-button-click